# Can the terms "Lambertian albedo" and "white-sky albedo" be used interchangeably?

Tags: reflection, radiation, radiative-transfer

To my knowledge the  "white-sky albedo" is the surface albedo corresponding to diffuse illumination while "black-sky albedo" corresponds to the direct illumination. I am confused with the term "Lambertian albedo" used in some radiative transfer models (e.g libRadtran). Is it the same with the "white-sky albedo"? If not, what is their difference?

Comment: Lambertian is more commonly used as an adjective to describe [how an object reflects light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambertian_reflectance), and is the definition of a perfectly diffuse reflector.  Specifically, Lambertian reflection is isotropic with respect to luminance, and luminous intensity obeys Lambert's Cosine Law.  'Lambertian' and 'white-sky' both approximately mean 'diffuse', but it's unclear if the terms have the exact same _technical_ meaning in the context of illumination.